# Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function in laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have the following code:

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rateYo').rateYo({
            starWidth: "40px"
        });

});
```

**show.blade.php**

```
  <div id="rateYo"></div>
```

And I'm getting error below:

> app.js:4586 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).rateYo is not a function
>   TypeError:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rateYo is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (main.js:3)

I'm using laravel 5.6 and everything is included fine as far as assets, any ideas on why this error is occurring?

Comment: Ensure that you've included `rateYo`'s JS file in your page before running the code. Observe the HTML of your page and see whether it is being rendered correctly.

Comment: How are you including your assets?

Comment: the jquery file is on the top, and main.js is after the jquery. Webpack is how im including it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `jquery.rateyo.min.js` see below its working fine when we add `jquery.rateyo.min.js` in to our code:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rateYo').rateYo({
            starWidth: "40px"
        });

});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
  
  <div id="rateYo"></div>
```

Comment: this works whenever i remove `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: this is interesting.